# Custom libevent is required with HipHop patches

Tags: linux, cmake, ubuntu-10.10, hiphop

I am trying to install hiphop on my pc but i am having problem with the cmake
am receiving this error:

```
CMake Error at CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake:65 (message):
Custom libevent is required with HipHop patches
```

any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this problem you have to patch the libevent source code, [here](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Building-and-installing) are the instruction of how to patch libevent source code.